# Pylance complaining on self.tr() method

Tags: python, qt, typechecking, pyside6, pylance

I'm developing an application with PySide6 6.6.2 and Python 3.11.8. Everything is working fine and mypy is happy. However, as I demonstrated on the following image, Pylance (on VSCode) keeps complaining that `self.tr()` cannot be accessed, though it actually should be acessible for any `QtCore.QObject` (and hence, `QtWidgets.QWidget`). In fact, the application runs with no errors and `pyside6-lupdate` or `pyside6-lrelease` are happy too.

[image: Pylance complaining: "Cannot access member 'tr' for type 'TestWidget*'. Member 'tr' is unknown.]

Here the example code:

```python
from PySide6 import QtWidgets


class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("Hello World!")))
```

AFAIK, Qt stubs are bundled with the library. Is there any reason why only this particular method isn't working? Why I would need to manually add stubs for a single method, while the entirety of the package is correctly type checked (note, for example, that `self.setLayout` and `self.layout()` are correctly typechecked)? This leads me to think something is wrong in the way I'm using QTranslator, and not with the library itself.

I tried to manually implement `self.tr()` this way:

```python
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("Hello World!")))

    def tr(self, text: str) -> str:
        return QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("TestWidget", text)
```

This makes Pylance happy and the application still works. However, it's rather weird that I need to manually implement this method, while the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_linguist.html#qt-linguist-example) itself uses them (and if I just download that example, same errors show up).

Someone can help me understand what's going on?

Comment: you can try to add a `.pyi` file that describes the methods of the type `QWidget`

Comment: @rioV8, I added more details to my question

Comment: is `tr()` a dynamic method or a static method (like you have added), PyLance does not handle dynamic methods, you have to do it with `pyi` files

Comment: show a link where `tr()` is defined in the Qt modules, where are the stubs defined/added

Comment: `self.tr` actually is the static [`QObject.tr()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#tr) function, maybe that's the problem: possibly the stubs are just missing it, or are not properly written. Note that in PyQt using `QObject.tr()` is discouraged (see [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/i18n.html#differences-between-pyqt6-and-qt)) and I suppose it's also the same for PySide: you should always prefer `QApplication.translate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @musicamante in replies, [`QObject.tr()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#tr) is a C++ static method for `QObject`s, and the docs says explicitly:

> Unfortunately, because of the way Qt implements tr() it is not possible for PyQt6 to exactly reproduce its behaviour. [...] The PyQt6 behaviour is unsatisfactory and may be changed in the future. It is recommended that `translate()` be used in preference to `tr()`. This is guaranteed to work with current and future versions of PyQt6 and makes it much easier to share message files between Python and C++ code.

Therefore, the implementation I wrote maybe is the way to go, using `QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate()` and, if wanted, manually implementing `self.tr()` for your classes.

Here the example from the link above:

```python
from PySide6 import QtCore
class A(QtCore.QObject):
    def hello(self):
        return QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate('A', "Hello")

a = A()
a.hello() # Correctly translated
```